# Windows printing: printer works locally, but over network it can't find driver

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, printer, network-printer

A friend has a Epson Stylus RX500 printer. She wants to share it between her WinXP desktop and her Win7 laptop.

The printer is connected direct to her WinXP desktop, and she can print fine from there.

But the Win7 laptop can't print -- it can see the shared printer on the network, but it can't find a driver for it. (And looking on the web, I don't see any Win7 drivers for it.)

However, if I connect the printer directly to the Win7 laptop, it works, it can print.

This suggests that there is a driver for it, but for some reason, it can't find a driver when connecting to the printer over the network.

My question is: **if a printer works when connected directly to the machine, should it still work over the local network**?

Answer (score 1):

Having had similar issues, especially with HP printers, try adding a printer port and select type as IP and connect to the printer using that port.

Answer (score 0):

If you W7 laptop is 64bit as opposed to 32bit, you are probably in for some issues.

Regardless, I would suggest taking the latest driver file (complete install executable) available for the RX500 (whether it be from VISTA or from XP) and install it on the W7 machine.

Once applied (and a reboot has occured), your should be able to print to the network printer with the downgraded driver.

Give it a shot.

Comment: Yeah, it is 64bit W7. The problem is, there's no Windows 7 driver available. At least, Epson had no such driver. (Calling support, they confirmed there is no Win7 driver for RX500.) But somehow, Windows 7 installs a driver that works for it when I connect locally. Does that make sense?